# How to mount filesystem automatically?

Tags: 16.04, mount, filesystem

I accidentally unmounted file system from ubuntu. So, when I open my laptop, every time I have to run below command in command screen to open gui.

mount -o remount, rw /

How can I mount file system permanently ?

Comment: You can't "accidentally' have unmounted / .. that is your root-filesystem. If / mounts read-only at boot, and must be remounted rw, something is seriously wrong. Either in /etc/fstab or in the filesystem itself.

Comment: Please refer to the above comment, act accordingly, and ignore ALL the half baked answers that don't address the problem in any constructive manner as of today.

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>super</kbd> and type "disks" to open `gnome-disk-utility`. On the left pane, select the disk/partition you want to mount at startup. On the right, click on the cog/gear icon, select "Edit Mount Options..." and check the "Mount at system startup" option.

[image]

Comment: where is this found as can't see it on ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Screenshot helps. :+1:
Should I un-tick "Show in user interface" option ? I have it ticked default.
(Upvoted but as my reputation is low you will get it once my reputation gets to some point)

Comment: @Tusher if it helps then click the arrow on the left of the answer for a real +1, +1 from me too!

Comment: @TusharSheth You don't HAVE to check "Show in user interface", it just means it'll show in your file manager (i.e. on your desktop, too). I'd recommend leaving it unchecked. What really matters is is the "Mount at system startup" option.

Comment: I did those steps. But still it asks for login and password, and 

mount -o remount, rw /  command to work as normal ubuntu system.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Disks tool.
Select the device on the right side, and then click on the gear icon. There is an option to edit the mounting options

Comment: I reached to the options. But what to do from there ? I have accidentally unmounted it first time. So can you please give me exact step to do this ? I am new to ubuntu and I think it is very risky to touch this files.

Comment: I'm gonna try. But please note that since I do not use the English version there may be variations.
1) Select Edit mounting actions 2) Unlock User Session Defaults  2) Unlock User Session Defaults
3) Mark Mount at startup and press OK